# How do I organize these abstract page object methods?

Tags: java, webdriver, abstract

This is really a general Java question but I figured it would be easier to explain with the specific Webdriver perspective from which it arose.

I have a complicated page object that I now want to make abstract, because I found another page that is very similar but different in key ways. Now many of my methods, which had returned instances of the page object, are broken. I want to keep the bulk of the code for these methods in the abstract class and still have them return instances of the new subclasses; these methods should return new instances of whatever subclass called them.

Here is an example with a navNextPage method which is common to both of the subclasses. This seems to work, but it feels wrong:

```
public abstract class PresContentPage {
     protected PresContentPage navNextPage() {
          // code to navigate to the next page goes here
          return null;
     }
}

public class MainContent extends PresContentPage {
     public MainContent navNextPage() {
          super.navNextPage();
          return new MainContent(...);
     }
}

// And so on with another subclass...
```

So, this does what I want: the code for the `navNextPage` method is siloed in the abstract class, but the version that gets called will return the page object of the type that invoked the method.

I just feel wrong having my protected method, which is not and cannot be void, return null. But since it's protected, and it's an abstract class, no one will ever be able to call it anyway, right? Does that make it okay? Is there a way better way to do this that I just never learned?

Another option I thought of is to just make a void method with a different name like `navNextPageVoid` and have the subclasses call that instead of `super.navNextPage`, but... that seems sort of gross in a different way.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Typically if you want to force a method to be implemented in a specialisation you make it [abstract in the generalisation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/abstract.html).  Therefore

> public abstract class PresContentPage {
>        abstract PresContentPage navNextPage(); }

Comment: Indeed, I could do that - but the implementation of the methods would be exactly the same - and use only data from the abstract class - apart from the final return statement. So I'm trying to keep the shared code in the abstract class rather than having two copies in each of the subclasses. Right now I've settled on having a navNextPageVoid method that does everything BUT the final return in the abstract class.